# WildFly doesn't read application.properties on SpringBoot project

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties, wildfly

I have a project with the structure below, It works when I use eclipse->Run As-> Spring Boot App, but if I run it on WildFly my application.properties is not readed. I know that, because when I execute in SpringBoot the url is http://localhost:8000/gigy/ and when I execute on WildFly the url is http://localhost:8080/springBootRestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/, I need to execute it on a server because I need to debug the program. I readed some similar posts but they did not work for me.

[image]

my application.properties

```
server.port=8000
server.contextPath=/gigy

logging.level.com.gigy=DEBUG

# Data source properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

and my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.whatever</groupId>
<artifactId>springBootRestApi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>springBootRestApi</name>
<description>whatever</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Is your problem that it's not acting on the `server.contextPath` setting?

Comment: In my POM? Plugin->configuration .... I don't know if it solve my problem because I need other configurations like spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate, port etc... Like my application.properties

Comment: The thing is that there is no way that a SpringBoot application can set the contextPath in anything other than when running as a pure SpringBoot application. However most of the other properties should work as usual

Comment: So... What's the point to use SpringBoot if we can't deploy it in a real server?

Comment: I don't think SpringBoot applications are intended to be deployed to "real" servers.